# animate height not working properly on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate the height of an image when user scrolls to the container of the image.

It works for the first time when scrollin downwards.

After that on scrolling up and down it is not working properly.

It flickers.

My code like this

```
function test($el) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height(),
    elemTop = $el.offset().top,
    elemBottom = elemTop + $el.height();
    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom)
     && (elemBottom <= docViewBottom) &&  (elemTop >= docViewTop) );
  }


  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if(windowWidth >= 680){ 
      $("#desktopGraphWrap, #phoneGraphWrap, #ipadGraphWrap").show();
      if(test($('div.figurette'))) {
        console.log('test success')
        $('.fadeAnim').fadeIn("fast", function(){
          $('#desktopGraph').animate({
            height:"96px"
          },"slow", function(){
            $('#ipadGraph').animate({
              height:"98px"
            },"slow", function(){
              $("#phoneGraph").animate({
                height:"84px"
              }, "slow", function(){
              });
            });
          });
        });
      }else{
        $('.fadeAnim').hide();
        $('#desktopGraph, #ipadGraph, #phoneGraph').animate({"height":0},"fast");
      }
    }else{
      $("#desktopGraphWrap, #phoneGraphWrap, #ipadGraphWrap").hide();
    }
  });
```

I want want the 'desktopGraph', 'phoneGraph' and 'ipadGraph' to ANIMATE HEIGHT FROM BOTTOM TO TOP.

When scrolling down it should reset its height to zero and whenever we scroll to the container div the animation should work.

The html like this

```
<div id="desktopGraphWrap"  class="">
    <img src="img/blue-bg-web.png" class="img-responsive fadeAnim">
    <img src="img/desktopGraph.png"  id="desktopGraph" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div id="phoneGraphWrap" class="">
    <img src="img/blue-bg-iphone.png" class="img-responsive fadeAnim">
    <img id="phoneGraph" src="img/phoneGraph.png" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div id="ipadGraphWrap" class="">
    <img src="img/blue-bg-ipad.png" class="img-responsive fadeAnim">
    <img id="ipadGraph"  src="img/ipadGraph.png" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

and the css like this..

```
#desktopGraph {
    position: absolute;
    width: 160px;
    height: 0px;
    left: 36px;
    bottom: -150px;
}
#phoneGraph {
    position: absolute;
    width: 47px;
    height: 0px;
    left: 287px;
    bottom: -172px;
}
.fadeAnim{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
#desktopGraphWrap .fadeAnim{
    left: 36px;
    bottom: -150px;
}
#phoneGraphWrap .fadeAnim {
    left: 287px;
    bottom: -172px;
}
#ipadGraphWrap .fadeAnim {
    left: 437px;
    bottom: -165px;
}
#ipadGraph {
    position: absolute;
    width: 73px;
    height: 0px;
    left: 437px;
    bottom: -165px;
}
#desktopGraphWrap, #phoneGraphWrap, #ipadGraphWrap{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
#desktopGraphWrap, #desktopGraphWrap .animateIn {
    height: 96px;
}
#phoneGraphWrap, #phoneGraphWrap .animateIn {
    height: 84px;
}
#ipadGraphWrap, #ipadGraphWrap .animateIn{
    height: 98px;
}
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Chanchalstack/s489M/7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/s489M/8/

I added [`.stop(true, true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop) before each of the `.animate()`'s. So now the first two are not flickering anymore, but staying visible when they are scrolled to.

```
 $('#desktopGraph').stop(true, true).animate({
                        height: $('#desktopGraph').height() == 0 ? 96 : 0
                    }, "slow", function () {
                        $('#ipadGraph').stop(true, true).animate({
                            height: $('#ipadGraph').height() == 0 ? 98 : 0
                        }, "slow", function () {
                            $("#phoneGraph").stop(true, true).animate({
                                height: $('#ipadGraph').height() == 0 ? 84 : 0
                            }, "slow");
```

Let me know if that is closer to what you want.

---

**EDIT :**

I played around with it some more, and now I got all three of them to stay put when scrolled to. I think this is how you want it. http://jsfiddle.net/s489M/9/

```
    if (!$('.fadeAnim').is(':visible')) {
        $('.fadeAnim').fadeIn("fast", function (event) {
            $('#desktopGraph').stop(true, true).animate({ //added .stop(true, true) here
                height: $('#desktopGraph').height() == 0 ? 96 : 0
            }, "slow", function() {
                $('#ipadGraph').stop().animate({ //added .stop() here
                    height: $('#ipadGraph').height() == 0 ? 98 : 0
                }, "slow", function() {
                    $("#phoneGraph").stop(true).animate({ // added .stop(true) here
                        height: $('#phoneGraph').height() == 0 ? 84 : 0
                    }, "slow");
                });
            });
            // event.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
} else {
    $('.fadeAnim').fadeOut("fast", function (event) {
        $('#desktopGraph, #ipadGraph, #phoneGraph').stop().animate({ //added .stop() here
            height: 0
        }, "fast");
        // event.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. This was what I wanted. But this is not working in firefox. Can you please help me with that too..

Comment: Yes.Thats right. It works on the fiddle but not on my website.Why should it happen? I am using twitter bootstrap in my website. thats the difference with the fiddle and website i think.

Comment: Yeah I checked the console and there i found no errors. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I fixed it. The issue was I gave float:left and position : relative to the wrapper div element. The float left worked in chrome but not in ff. So I had to remove that float :left style and position the inner elements accordingly.